# dovecot и Directory index full

Tags: ubuntu, imap, dovecot

Всем привет. подскажите пожалуйста с проблемой

```
EXT4-fs warning (device sdb): ext4_dx_add_entry:2199: inode #524328: comm imap: Directory index full!
```

Есть dovecot который 5 лет работал и накопил миллионы файлов в одной папке. Я не могу прочитать эти файлы или посмотреть их размеры и тд. Можно ли как то средствами dovecot раскидать их в подпапки, умеет ли dovecot работать с под папками? сейчас dovecot использует maildir движок для хранения. поможет ли переход на mdbox не получить такое через время?
df -i говорит что ноды есть

```
/dev/sdb       26214400 6192578 20021822   24%
```

ubuntu16 x64

Comment: А что такое mdbox? Может быть mbox?

Comment: да все верно, имел ввиду mbox

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/srg/blog/462967/ - возможно тут найдёшь ответ.